# Will cookies be preserved when restarting the Tor Browser after an automatic update?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, cookies

On my computer, Tor Browser automatically updated itself. After the update, I am presented with this message whenever I try to access a website:

[image: Tor Browser message]

I could restart the browser, but I currently have some cookies I want to keep. If I choose restart the browser by clicking on the blue button, will the cookies be preserved, or will they be lost?

Comment: No, they won't be. Cookies are deleted in Tor browser once the browser is closed.

Comment: This is an unfortunate side effect of automatic updates, and the message doesn't seem to have been updated for the Tor Browser. This would make a good issue on Tor's Gitlab if it doesn't exist already.